# Scraping data from HTML Table with different classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a web scraper for creating covid-19 datasets for my data visualization project. I need this table from https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
page = requests.get(url,verify=True)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,features="lxml")

rows = soup.select("tr")


for data in rows:
    print(data.text)
```

I am getting desired output but at each row(country) it also displays continent name which i dont want to include in my dataset. Is there any solution?
As i am new to webscraping, I need all the help i can get.

Update: This is html code, and the last td specifying "europe" is not needed in dataset.

```
<tr style="" role="row" class="odd">
<td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:15px; text-align:left;"><a class="mt_a" href="country/uk/">UK</a></td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right" class="sorting_1">211,364</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right;"></td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right;">31,241 </td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right;"></td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">N/A</td>
<td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">179,779</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">1,559</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">3,114</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">460</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">1,631,561</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">24,034</td>
<td style="display:none" data-continent="Europe">Europe</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You need to be more precise on what you want to select. The current code selects all `tr` tags without more information. Maybe, you only want to select `tr` elements for a precise `table` ?

Comment: And additional to the previous comment, you can always exclude the last 'td' from the data, while processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. The key function with beautifulSoup are `find` and `findAll`. Read the full doc / example below. You should manage to gather what you want.

---

EDIT: the continet have a 'data-continent' attributes. You should then loop for rows without this attribute.
Note this is note the same for the 'World' line, so I have 'manually' ignored it.
Here is the modified code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"
page = requests.get(url,verify=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,features="lxml")

# find the table with id: 'main_table_countries_today'
table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'main_table_countries_today'})
body = table.find('tbody')

# looping through all rows, without 'data-continent' attribute :
for row in body.findAll('tr', {'data-continent': None}):
    print('\nParsing a new line:')
    values = row.findAll('td')
    # looping through all cells inside the row, ignoring the 'World' one:
    if values[0].text != 'World':
        for val in values:
            print(val.text)
```

and the result is:

```
Parsing a new line:

Parsing a new line:
USA
1,322,223
+438
78,622 
+7
223,749
1,019,852
16,978
3,995
238
8,638,846
26,099
North America

Parsing a new line:
Spain
262,783
+2,666
26,478 
+179
173,157
63,148
1,741
5,620
566
1,932,455
41,332
Europe

Parsing a new line:
Italy
217,185

30,201 

99,023
87,961
1,168
3,592
500
2,445,063
40,440
Europe
[...]
```

Comment: Vatican City
12

 

2
10

14,981



Europe //Thank you for the response, this code works but it still displays continent name at end which is what i want to remove!

Answer (score 0):

Your code fetches all the `tr` tags irrespective of their position. You need to specify the table. You are interested in the data in the first table body.

```py
response = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautfiulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
tbody = soup.find('tbody') # Selecting the first tbody
rows = tbody.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    print(row.text)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils
html = '''
<tr style="" role="row" class="odd">
<td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:15px; text-align:left;"><a class="mt_a" href="country/uk/">UK</a></td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right" class="sorting_1">211,364</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right;"></td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right;">31,241 </td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right;"></td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">N/A</td>
<td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">179,779</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">1,559</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">3,114</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">460</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">1,631,561</td>
<td style="font-weight: bold; text-align:right">24,034</td>
<td style="display:none" data-continent="Europe">Europe</td>
</tr>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
rows = doc.selects('tr').selects('td')
for data in rows:
  print(data.notContains('display:none',attr="style").text)
```

Result:

```
['UK', '211,364', '', '31,241', '', 'N/A', '179,779', '1,559', '3,114', '460', '1,631,561', '24,034']
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples